# The most confusing concepts in weight loss

Tags: exercise, weight-loss, sugar, carbohydrates

Here are some of the subjects that I found so confusing :

> Try to eat good Carbs/Sugar not the bad ones (simple / complex ):

Checked internet and from what I understood that they are quite similar but the chemical structure is different. 
The differences between the structures makes the absorption more slow for the complex carbs ( and non processed sugar ).

The question is does the fact of the slow absorption is really good?

The way I understand this: At the end it's a matter of time until these Carbs get absorbed and turned into fat, so it is just a matter of time!

> Abs exercices will not burn the belly fat!

They also explained that you can't burn a specific area of your body ( this one makes a sense for me ). But saying that doing abs exercices will not burn the fat around your belly - I cannot trust this fact easily: what I'm burning then? Fuel?

No blog post explained in deep why you should this and shouldn't eat that, basically the same information is duplicated in all blogs.

Comment: this at least two questions, maybe more. You'll find some already here about carbs in general and simple/complex. On the second one, they mean that ab exercises use up all your fat, not just belly fat, and arm exercises use up all your fat, not just arm fat, etc. How to lose weight is a very broad and complicated topic that can't be covered in a single question on this site.

Comment: [My answer on simple/complex carbs](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/12693) may help with your first question.

Comment: The human body is a machine that has evolved to be fine tuned to survive with whatever Nature can provide, and it has evolved to be very robust, it's not a fragile machine prone to go off the rails unless micromanaged by calorie counting etc. (you have to ask how we could even exist today if that were the case). This means that we have the right enzymes to extract the glucose in exactly the right way (not too fast, not too slow)  for us provided the carbs come in the natural form. Refined carbs will then be absorbed way too fast.

Comment: Avoiding junk foods will definitely help you in losing weight. Consume green tea, this helps to reduce the fat content in the body and regular exercise like jogging and swimming will surely help you to drop weight.